# Linq query to consider even records and skip odd record

Tags: c#, linq

Below is my model :

```
public class MyData
{
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public List<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public int? TestId { get; set; }
    public List<SubTest> SubTests { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my method :

```
private void MyMethod(int testId, int lastTestId)
{
    var list = new List<MyData>();//contains some records
    if (testId == 0)
    {
        var test1 = list[0].Tests[0];
        var test2 = list[0].Tests[1];
        var regionIds = new List<int>();
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            counter = 0;
            foreach (var test in item.Tests)
            {
                if (test.SubTests.Count != 0 && counter % 2 != 0)
                    regionIds.Add(item.RegionId);

                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var test1 = list[0].Tests[0];
        var regionIds = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            counter = 0;
            foreach (var test in item.Tests)
            {
                if (test.SubTests.Count != 0)
                    regionIds.Add(item.RegionId);

                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above method when testId will be 0, then I will have 2 records in Tests and when TestId > 0 then I will have only 1 record in Tests.

Now I am trying to find those region ids for which there is no `SubTests(SubTest.Count=0)` for a test, but when I will have 2 test then I want to consider last test and count subTest for that last test.

My code is working fine, but I have some code duplication, which I want to simplify.

Instead of loop I would prefer Linq, but as I was not knowing that how to do this with linq, I used a for loop.

**Update:**

Input :

```
[0] : Region = "abc"
      RegionId = 1
      "TestList": 
       [
         {
           TestId : 100,
           SubTests  : //contains some records
         },
         {
           TestId : 101,
           SubTests  : //contains some records
         },
       ],
[1] : Region = "Pqr",
      RegionId = 2
      "TestList": 
       [
         {
           TestId : 100,
           SubTests  : //contains some records
         },
         {
           TestId : 101,
           SubTests  : //No records i.e count = 0
         },
       ],
[2] : Region = "Lmn",
      RegionId = 3
      "TestList": 
       [
         {
           TestId : 100,
           SubTests  : //No records i.e count = 0
         },
         {
           TestId : 101,
           SubTests  : //No records i.e count = 0
         }
       ]
```

**Expected Output :**

```
[2,3]
```

How can I simplify this process?

Comment: give example of input and expected output

Comment: @ASh:I have updated my question to include sample inputs and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<MyData> list; 
...
int[] ids = list.Where(x => x.Tests.Last().SubTests.Count == 0)
                .Select(x => x.RegionId)
                .ToArray();
```

expression in `Where` methods can be explained as "last test in Tests collection doesn't have subtests".

after we found all requiered tests from list we get their `RegionId` with Select method and save in array.

Comment: @Learning, Linq method `Last()` returns last object from sequence. If there is only one, that one will be last

Answer (score 2):

Linq's `Select` and `Where` methods have an override where the lambda expression includes both the object and its index

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx

```
list.Where((item,index) => index % 2 == 0)
```

Here's a fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/GZippb